# Counting Balls in $L^2_m[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, weak-lp-spaces

**Setup and Thoughts to Date**

---

Let $B$ be the closed unit ball in ${L}^2_m[0,1]$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, equipped with the weak topology.  I know that $B$ is separable, so there exists a separating sequence $(f_n \in L^2_m[0,1])_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that *(here's I've used Riez to identify $L^2_m[0,1]$ with its topological dual)*
$$
d^{\star}(x,y)\triangleq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{f_n(x-y)}{2^n},
$$
defines a metrizes $B$ under the weak topology on $L^2_m[0,1]$.

The Banach-Alaoglou theorem, implies that $B$ is a compact metric space under this metric.  Therefore the open cover
$$
\mathcal{U}\triangleq \left\{
\overline{Ball\left(x;\frac1{2}\right)}
\right\}_{x \in B},
$$
admits a *finite* subcover.

---

**Question**
My question is, what is the cardinality of this finite sub-cover?

Comment: Can you use geometric series arguments to compute it?

Comment: Not sure how that would work?  Compute the limiting number?